# Having error destructring a value from redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am having error while trying to get my redux state value. This is my redux store configuration below

index.js

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';


let persistor = persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
    <App />
    </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

store.js

```
import loginReducer from './reducers/auth.slice';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  login: loginReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  middleware: [thunk],
});

export default store;
```

auth.slice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
};

const loginSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'login',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    pending: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
    },
  },
});

const { actions, reducer } = loginSlice;

export const {
  pending,
} = actions;

export default reducer;
```

When I then try to use `isLoading` like this

```
const { isLoading } = useSelector(state => state.login);
```

I get this error below

```
×
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isLoading' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please try to use useAppSelector for global use. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-typed-hooks this works for me. don't know why.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, though Still not working